# Is it possible to record meetings through Alexa?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I want to record some public events through Alexa. Is this possible? As far as I know Alexa only records on a DVR. How can I tell alexa to record the specific event on a specific dvr?

Does this require building a custom skill?
Maybe by using https://developer.amazon.com/de-DE/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-recordcontroller.html

Please guide me through.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

No, it's not possible.  Alexa isn't a dictation or recording device.
The Video Recorder interface you found probably relates to controlling an Alexa-compatible DVR device via voice.

Comment: It definitely has the APIs for it, do you think there is some privacy-related limit in there?

Comment: so we cannot dictate it to record on a DVR? but can we somehow send the voice to some other server for processing? 

E.g. Can Alexa continue listening and send the sound waves to a server?

Comment: No, you cannot send Alexa recorded audio anywhere as an independent developer.   Amazon control the voice processing aspects of Alexa. You cannot do what you're looking to do with Alexa.